# postgres on AWS, intermittened hang on simple sql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

This should be a very simple sql on a small table with light traffic and only 4 columns.  I am running on an AWS EC2 with an RDS (postgres) the EC2 is running node. I'm calling a rest API that
is doing the below sql.  The table in question has maybe 200 rows.

The table def is

```
tableid:  integer  (PK) (not null)
playerid:  text    (PK) (not null)
seatpos:  integer  (not null)
prefs:   json
```

So I need to do an upsert (insert/update) of a player.  At first I did a
select * where playerid=x and tableid = y;
base on the result I would do an insert or an update. What I found form looking at the logs
was that sometimes the select would never return. This seems very odd as its just a simple read
on the PK.

So I changed it to an upsert sql

```
INSERT INTO seating(tableid, playerid, seatpos, userPrefs)
VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT seating_pkey DO update set seatpos=$3, userprefs=$4;
```

$1,$2,$3,$4 being replaced with appropriate values.

This seemed to work better but no... having the same issue again. I haven't been able to
trace the logs again as I need a consistent recurrance to really debug it but I have not reason
to think it won't be at the same place.

How can I debug this?  what would cause postgres to just hang.  Maybe some implicit lock?  what can I look at in either pgadmin or though AWS. I'm not a DBA looked around as much as I can and didn't see anything.

I'm assuming the PK also creates an index. I have not made an explicit index.

Looking at similar issues online and someone said to look at wait states and I see the below. I run the query to get this several time and it stays the same. This doesn't look healthy

```
        state      wait_event_type     wait_event
1       null          Activity           LogicalLaunchMain
2       null          Activity           AutoVacuumMain
3       idle          Client             ClientRead
4       idle          Client             ClientRead
5       idle          Client             ClientRead
6       idle          Client             ClientRead
7       idle          Client             ClientRead
8       idle          Client             ClientRead
9       idle          Client             ClientRead
10      active         null                null
11      null          Activity           BgWriteMain
12      null          Activity           CheckpointerMain
13      null          Activity           WalWriterMain
```

I do have AWS backing up the DB every 2-3 days but that is the only thing I can think of, And of course I need to do backups.

Comment: "What I found form looking at the logs was that sometimes the select would never return"  Which logs, and what specifically are you seeing in them which you think indicates this?

Comment: Your pg_stat_activity indicates that one connection is doing something on the CPU (we don't know what) and 7 others are waiting for the client to send them work to do.  There is nothing inherently wrong with this, maybe you have a connection pooler that likes to hang on to idle connections in case demand increases soon.  But things might be easier to debug if you turn off that feature, or turn of the connection pooler entirely.

Comment: by Logs I mean my application logs from the node server.  I just rebooted the RDS instance and now no queries seem to work from my node server, though I can run them from pgadmin. I'm access through Node which is single threaded and using the pg NPM module. I dont think i am doing connection pooling unless that is on by default.  I do have a job that runs every min looking to do notifications. but that is the only background job that runs

Comment: Why do you think one connection is doing something with the CPU?  all the client entries are idle. the only active item is "null", "null"

Comment: Yeah, that is how cpu usage presents.

Comment: The active session might be you running the query. That looks like you didn't catch the slow execution in the act. Do you get log entries if you set `log_min_duration_statement` appropriately?